# Which condition is faster?

Tags: java

I'm developing a code with lots of iterations
and I was wondering which one of these conditions is more efficient.

```
//1
Boolean.FALSE.equals(x)
//2
x == false
//3
!x
```

I am using the first one but i am not sure about it. If someone can give some information and help me I will appreciate it.

Comment: `Boolean.False.equals(x)` wouldn't compile, unless you've got a custom `Boolean` class.

Comment: when you test it, do you notice any difference?

Comment: First, what is `x` ? Second, don't bother to improve that line, this is not necessary, the compiler will do it for you. Last, think about readability too.

Comment: I don't notice any difference it takes a lot of time cause the app is massive. I will care about the readability too. Thank you very much.

Comment: The normal convention to check `x` is false is `!x`. I recommend you follow the convention.

Comment: Wrong question. :-) The correct question is: which is more readable and maintainable?

Comment: These statements are not equivalent if `x` is of type `Boolean` - the first one yields `false` for `null`, the other two throw `NullPointerException`s in case of `null`

Comment: What type is `x`, `boolean` or `Boolean` ?

Comment: Why don't you write a microbenchmark to measure it? http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second and third one shoud be the fastest. The first one involves extra overhead, although it could well be that the JIT compiler optimises it.

The issue is more about readability. The first one is practically unreadable.

At popular request, I've expanded the answer a bit. I wrote this class:

```
package com.severityone.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean x = false;
        final boolean a = Boolean.FALSE.equals(x);
        final boolean b = x == false;
        final boolean c = !x;
    }
}
```

This is the resulting byte code:

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class com.severityone.test.Main {
  public com.severityone.test.Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/Boolean.FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       5: iconst_0
       6: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      12: istore_2
      13: iconst_1
      14: istore_3
      15: iconst_1
      16: istore        4
      18: return
}
```

What we can see from here is that numbers 2 and 3 take two instructions each, whereas number 1 takes five. For most programs, it won't make any difference, but if you're running in a tight loop, it could make a difference.

As for readability, the adage of "less is more" goes. Because my eyes aren't exactly 100%, I have problems with large amounts of text, so I prefer to put plenty of whitespace in my code. If you need to write `Boolean.FALSE.equals(x)`, and it's actually the `x` that you're interested in, you need to mentally swap the whole thing around.

As for the other two, readability is mostly a matter of personal preference. There's something to be said for all three options:

1. `!x`
2. `x == false`
3. `false == x`

The `!` can be easy to overlook if you have a very long expression, such as `!((value < 0 || value > 10) && "yes".equals(response))`. Some people prefer to write `... == false` or `false == ...`, because you don't easily miss it.

Comment: Your answer is mostly your opinion. It would be nice to add some bytecode to confirm the first part.

Comment: I've updated it, but had to wait until I got home, which is why it took a while.